# cygwin python pip + module calls: exit without anything

Tags: python, module, cygwin, pip

Hy,
Sorry if this question was asked before, but I really couldnt find any helpful answer.

Running any python script in **cygwin-terminal** that uses modules that werent installed using cygwin-setup will **just quit the python script** without any output. Whats wrong?

Example:

`import websocket`

`print "Done";`

gives me a blank line and returns to the shell. Whereas

`#import websocket`

`print "Done";`

prints 
`Done`

python scripts using i.e. 
`import hmac, base64, hashlib, urllib, urllib2, time, gzip, json, io, types, datetime, os`
work fine.

I have:

-Cygwin64 on Win7-64bit using the mintty-terminal

-installed all python27 packages i found useful using setup.exe -> python is working

-i did run ez_setup.py under cygwin:

`Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg`
`Processing dependencies for setuptools==2.1`
`Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==2.1`

-did run get-pip.py:

`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg`
`Cleaning up...`

I have a copy of python27 on c:\python27 too. not using cygwin, but windows-cmd and using that python executable the above script works.
I need cygwin because i want to use curses and ansi codes etc but not use a virtual ubuntu or stuff.

I have:

`$ ls -l python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None   13 18. Jan 11:12 python -> python2.7.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None   13 18. Jan 11:12 python2 -> python2.7.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Administrator None 7187  3. Okt 05:39 python2.7.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Administrator None 1669  3. Okt 05:39 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None   16 18. Jan 11:12 python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None   16 18. Jan 11:12 python-config -> python2.7-config`

also running 
`pip`
gives me a blank line and back comes the shell. whereas running pip in windows-cmd under c:\python27\scripts\ gives me:
`Usage:`
....

but running easy_install works:

`$ easy_install`
`error: No urls, filenames, or requirements specified (see --help)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. `pip` and `pip2` run in the same way : no answer, even with only `--version` or `--help` option. `pip3` does a core dump.
I found a hugly work around : remove `cygwin64` and go back to `cygwin`. 
If it could be helpful....

And it seems it has something to do with this issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1448